# JasperReport server

Tags: software-installation, 22.04, kubernetes

I use Ubuntu 22.04. How to deploy JasperReport server in Kubernetes?
I have the license file. I have access to the GitHub repository where the src for jasperReport, but I still need a bit of understanding of the whole process.

Comment: what is you linux distro/version?

Comment: my linux version 22.04

Comment: I also asked which distro. Please read [ask] then [edit] your question. Comments are for US to ask you questions for clarification 

Comment: Distributor = Ubuntu   and release = 22.04.3 TLS